# lua script editor for w32 application

Tags: lua

I need to add some script support for an old w32 MFC application. It should be possible for user to enter a custom formulas for further calculation. It should be very simple edit control with syntax highlights and error messaging. Do any solutions for lua(activx or dll) which may be embedded to my application exist?

Answer (score 0):

[Scintilla](http://scintilla.org/) includes a Lua lexer and provides syntax highlighting and more. Error messages can be displayed as [annotations](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Annotations).